# switch statements on json for peticuler key format objects

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to match the different format set of keys and want display set of  values of the same keys and using that values want to frame command, which i am expecting based on the key.

ex :  So if I see key1 key2 then I want to display the value in key1 key2 in one format(i.e i am framing commands using this two key values by giving the keys dynamically).

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonAsText = '''[

    {

        "command": "iTest",
        "testname": "BOV-VDSL-link-Rateprofile-CLI-Test-1",
        "params": {
            "obj1": "n2x_variables/config_file:C:/Program Files(x86)/Agilent/N2X/RouterTester900/UserData/config/7.0EA SP1 Release/OSP Regression/BOV/Bov-data-1-single-rate-profile.xml",
            "obj2": "n2x_variables/port_list:303/4 303/1"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "command": "iTest",
        "testname": "BOV-VDSL-link-Rateprofile-CLI-Test-2",
        "params": {
            "obj1": "n2x_variables/config_file:C:/Program Files(x86)/Agilent/N2X/RouterTester900/UserData/config/7.30 EA SP1 Release/OSP Regression/BOV/Bov-data-1-single-rate-profile.xml",
            "obj2": "n2x_variables/port_list:303/4 303/1"
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "iTest",
        "testname": "BOV-VDSL-link-Rateprofile-CLI-Test-3"
    }
]'''
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(jsonAsText)
```

From above code dynamically i want to give set of keys which i want from one set and fetch "jsonAsText"object elements baed on my requirements like suppose : if i gave format like kays **command** and **testname** then i am expecting to display 3rd set of parameters that is

```
{

 "command":"iTest",
 "testname":"BOV-VDSL-link-Rateprofile-CLI-Test-3"
}
```

should display and i will use these values to frame my command like below,

`println (result.command+" "+result.testname);`

or if my requirement is as below then

`println (result.command+" "+result.testname+" "+result.params.obj1+" "+result.params.obj2);`

I don't no whether i have explained my issue properly or not, but can any one please give me answer or code to achieve my requirement.